# Compare two lists and get unique list (example.txt) java

Tags: java

I found here a good code that will help me to finish a thing to do.
But what I need:
I have two lists, one list is example1.txt and sencond list is example2.txt I need to get similar and different. I dont know where to set the c://example1.txt and c://example2.txt

for example: Arrays.asList(c://example1.txt);

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Repeated {
      public static void main( String  [] args ) {

          Collection<String> listOne = Arrays.asList("1","2","3");

          Collection<String> listTwo = Arrays.asList("1","2","2");

          Collection<String> similar = new HashSet<String>( listOne );
          Collection<String> different = new HashSet<String>();
          different.addAll( listOne );
          different.addAll( listTwo );

          similar.retainAll( listTwo );
          different.removeAll( similar );

          System.out.printf("One:%s%nTwo:%s%nSimilar:%s%nDifferent:%s%n", listOne, listTwo, similar, different);
      }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Reading the lists from a file?

Comment: My problem is 
File1.txt
1
2
3
4
5

File2.txt
2
3
4

I need to get similar and the different informational
Similar = 2,3,4
Different = 1,5

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, you don't know how to read the text files to lists. There are many options:

- [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) `IOUtils.readLines(new FileInputStream("c:/example.txt"))`
- use `new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(..))` and then loop using the   `readLine()` method

To handle encoding properly you will need to use `new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8")`

**Update:**

It seems your file contains only one line. Using the `FileUtils` that Peter reminded me of:

```
String str = FileUtils.readFileToString("c:/filename.txt");
String[] numbers = str.split(",");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(numbers);
```

Comment: quote: "I dont know where to set the c://example1.txt and c://example2.txt for example: Arrays.asList(c://example1.txt);" - this is the only question I could extract.

Comment: Ihave a file ex1.txt in this file I have 1,2,3,4,5 and in second file I have ex2.txt inside the file I have 2,3,4,5 now I need to get similar and the different between these two files.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like homework, but I will bite.  I would use FileUtils

```
Set<String> example1 = new LinkedHashSet<String>(
                               FileUtils.readLines(new File(args[0])));
Set<String> example2 = new LinkedHashSet<String>(
                               FileUtils.readLines(new File(args[1])));
Set<String> same = new LinkedHashSet<String>(example1);
same.retainAll(example2);
Set<String> different = new LinkedHashSet<String>(example1);
different.removeAll(example2);
```

if you have one `,` between values you can use

```
Set<String> example1 = new LinkedHashSet<String>(
   Arrays.asList(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(args[0])).split("[,\\s]")));
```